# How to make most stupid synchronization ever?

Tags: windows-7, sync

I am using different PC-s at work, at home and at weekdays. And often I have to work from home and on weekdays. I am a little bit tired of clouds,misused subversion, external drives, setting up server connections, forwarding ports ..etc.

*I would like to use Visual Studio, SQL server and other programs that cant be installed on external HDD.*

Because there are three PC's is there any way to install "three sets of drives"
*(disk drives, display adapters, network adapters, processor ..etc)*

And then just carry around one HDD with OS programs and data, without need to synchronize.

*I wold like to do this on Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit.*

*I could manage to have same motherboards chipset and processors  if anything of this is possible.*

(editet @grawity, @CharlieRB because of unclear question, thanks)

Comment: What is the difference between "external drives" and "carry around one HDD with OS programs and data"? Seems like the same thing with exception of everything being on one HDD. Think of the risk of data loss.

Comment: For example, I cant install Visual Studio on external HDD and use it on different computer. I will backup my data, that is not issue.

Comment: Putting it that way, it makes sense. The way the question is written makes it sound more like you are concerned with the hassles of data synchronization/sharing/backup. You may want to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the OS. So, sure, that should work just fine by default on Linux (as long as you stick to the open-source graphics drivers, not proprietary ones); I've seen this done. Same with most BSDs.

Windows could deal with this too, except for the activation issues when the CPU & motherboard change. But [Windows To Go](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/devices/windowstogo.aspx) can be carried in a USB drive if you have (can obtain) the necessary Windows 8.1 version.

Comment: Is there anything like Windows to Go for Windows 7?